# mySQL : merge data from 3 tables in one result with one query statement

Tags: mysql, sql

To merge invoice- and corresponding client-adress data from an `invoice` and a `clients` table in one query I use this statement :

```
SELECT * 
FROM invoice, clients 
WHERE invoice.client_id = clients.ID
```

It works perfect. But now I have a third table coming into the game where invoice_items are stored. Each invoice has one or more items for whom the client will be charged. And each invoice_item `UPDATE` stores the corresponding, previous generated, invoice.ID. But how to merge 3 tables in one query ? I tried it like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM invoice, invoice_item, clients 
WHERE inv_num =:num 
AND invoice.client_id = clients.ID  
AND invoice_item.inv_id = invoice.ID
```

But I have no success so far. What do I do wrong ?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT : The whole statement looks like this :

```
$query = $this->db_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM invoice, invoice_item, clients  WHERE inv_num =:num AND invoice.client_id = clients.ID AND invoice_item.inv_id = invoice.ID');
$query->bindValue(':num',$val, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$success = $query->execute();
```

$val is the invoice number selected previously from a table.

UPDATE :

With the answer from Stivan I get following result schema.
Assume There is 1 invoice with 2 invoice_item's :

```
    Array {
     [0] => Array {
            // col from table `invoice`
            [col 1]
            [col 2]
            [col n] 
            // col from table `invoice_item`
            [col 1]
            [col 2]
            [col n] 
            // col from table `clients`
            [col 1]
            [col 2]
            [col n] 
      }
     [1] => Array {
            // col from table `invoice`
            [col 1]
            [col 2]
            [col n] 
            // col from table `invoice_item`
            [col 1]
            [col 2]
            [col n] 
            // col from table `clients`
            [col 1]
            [col 2]
            [col n] 
      }
   }
```

In other words within each array I get `all columns` from the participating tables with redundant content in table `invoice` and `clients`.

How to delimit the columns from `clients` to `1 col` only ?

Or even better saving recources and recieve only 1 array with * from invoice and attached items from `invoice_items`, so it may looks like this :

```
Array {
 [0] => Array {
        // col from table `invoice`
        [col 1]
        [col 2]
        [col n] 
        // col from table `clients`
        [col 1]
   }
         Array {
            [0] => Array {
                   // col from table `invoice_items`
                   [col 1]
                   [col 2]
                   [col n] 
                  }
            [1] => Array {
                   // col from table `invoice_items`
                   [col 1]
                   [col 2]
                   [col n] 
                  }
          }
 }
```

Comment: How is your existing query not working?  Does it produce an error or just return no results.  Might be helpful to post your table structure, sample data, and expected results.

Comment: $success is false when I use the statement with 3 tables

Comment: Why not use joins?

Comment: well ... I haven't tried yet, I am not a poweruser ...

Comment: @Ben Try my example and let me know if it works, If you are getting error then try to run without the `where` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
     *
from invoice
     left join invoice_item on invoice_item.inv_id = invoice.ID
     left join clients on clients.ID = invoice.client_id
where
     invoice.inv_num = :num;  //Or the table where inv_number comes from

 corrected invoice.inv_number to invoice.inv_num
```

Comment: Bingo - it works, perfect. I have 2 invoice items (records) stored in the invoice_table for 1 invoice and I get 2 arrays back with both items pointing to the one inv_id. That's correct ?

Comment: @Ben Yes you are passing a specific inv_num as long as that's the data you expect to see it should be correct

Comment: Yes it does. I must correct myself again. In my comment above I wrote ínvoice_table but I meant `invoice_item` table. Anyway, I guess I need to study `JOINS` ;-)

Comment: @Ben Yes, I used left join in your case because I'm not sure how your tables are structured and what data is in each table